# Counting number of guests in delimited string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, substitution

I have a Google Sheets cell containing a list of people attending an event. Some of the guests will bring friends. So the cell (A1) can look like this:

```
Ben, Sarah + 2, James , Mary + 5
```

I need to count the total number of people attending, which in this case is 11. And so I was thinking of using a formula along these lines:

```
=count(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+",","),","))
```

But this doesn't work because it's only counting the numbers as 1 item, and the COUNT function doesn't appear to work.

How can I make this work, so that it correctly gives the number of attendees as 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the total sum by doing this:

`=if(regexmatch(A1,"\+"),sum(ArrayFormula(query(split(transpose(split(A1,",")),"\+"),"select count(Col1), sum(Col2)",0))),if(isblank(A1),"",counta(split(A1,","))))`

[image]

### Explanation:

- `if(regexmatch(A1,"\+"), something, if(isblank(A1),"",counta(split(A1,","))))` => if there are not `+` signs in the answer, then check if the cell is empty or not, if empty, print blank, else just count how many people are between commas, otherwise calculate with the *plus ones*. (explanation below)
- `split(A1,",")),"\+")` => red area => will separate the cell by commas, and the result can be seen in the red area in the picture
- `split(TRANSPOSE(split(A1,",")),"\+")` => green area => will loop through each of the results above and separate to a cell on the right the values that have a `+` sign between them, can be seen in the green area in the image
- `query(split(TRANSPOSE(split(A1,",")),"\+"),"select count(Col1), sum(Col2)",0)` => blue area => then we will query the 2 columns, in the left one we want to count the number of rows in that column (the columns with the names), on the next column we want to sum the values (the plus ones)
- `sum(ArrayFormula(query(split(transpose(split(A1,",")),"\+"),"select count(Col1), sum(Col2)",0)))` => yellow area => then we will sum the values of the 2 columns to get the final result

Comment: Thanks for your answer @nabais. When there are no added guests it gives an error. So when the cell contains "Ben, Sarah , James , Mary" it gives a #value error. How can this be fixed?

Comment: updated my answer, check now please to see if it works for you @TimB

Comment: Thanks @nabais. Just one last problem, if the cell is empty then it shows the result as 1, rather than zero. Should I just use if(A1="","", .....) or is there a better way to amend the formula?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following formula

```
=IF(LEN(A2), 
     SUM(COUNTA(SPLIT(A2,",")), 
         IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"\D"," ")," "))),"")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
- [`COUNTA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)